# "The value of y is handled as parameter of the function" What does it mean?

Tags: optimization, expected-value, quantum-computation

It's a statement from an optimization paper, where we have a random variable $X$ taking up values $\in \Omega_X = [0,7]$ and a decision variable $y \in \mathbb{R}^d$ , and a function $f: \Omega_X \times \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

We are interested in finding

$$ y^{*} \in \text{argmin}_y \mathbb{E}[f(X,y)]$$

We will be using a classical optimization routine to find the optimal value $y^{*}$. The value of $y$ is handled as parameter of the function $f(X,y) = f_y(X)$ .

What does it mean? Since my function is
$$ f(X,y) = (y-X)c$$ where $c=0.05$

How does it changes my function?

Comment: It's from this paper [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.10780.pdf), I have to follow an optimization routine to find the optimal value of $y$